# PHP and Edge compatibility

Tags: php, microsoft-edge

My website functionality is broken on Edge (Especially success/error messages and Login) and I was told it has something to do with the session.cookie_lifetime.

Please note, I'm not a developer and I do not have any code knowledge.

Comment: Browser incompatibility usually happens on the client side not the server side, so you should be looking at the HTML of the login page, not the PHP. Can you post that? You can simply do view-source on the page or give us a link to it.

Comment: the link to the website is www.MineVotes.com

Comment: Can you provide more detail of what happens when you try using Edge? Not many people here will have Edge installed so hard to reproduce.

Comment: So when you try to login - the login won't work. Doesn't matter if you put the right ID + pass or not, it will just refresh the page (I believe thats what it does). Also, it doesn't show the error or success messages on Edge (If you try to enter a random id + password, you'll see the error message above it, all these errors/success messages do not appear on edge). But the main problem is the login functionality itself.

Comment: You need to employ a better developer.

Answer (score 0):

Your website has no PHP session cookie in Edge.
This problem may be related to it: [IE / Edge session cookie problems using cookie_lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048551/ie-edge-session-cookie-problems-using-cookie-lifetime)

So your question now should be about edge not having any php sessionid cookie.

Comment: Could you check the source in the website itself? its minevotes.com

Comment: When I open the network tab in Edge (F12) and submit the post it actually has no values in Edge. In a quick look I could not find what is causing this. I think you should ask your developer to debug this.

Comment: Unfortunately he is not available to do so :/ Thats why I came here.

Comment: I spent 10 minutes searching but could not really find the issue.
When I change the name of the login button from login to login2 the page redirects to the homepage, so edge does actually send something to your server.

You could temporary change:
$redirect = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
To var_dump($_POST);exit; and see what the output is.

Comment: Hmm, I made a test page to try that out - you can see the results in minevotes.com/registertest - I have no knowledge of code whatsoever so I can't really tell what it means xd

Comment: Your post data is actually submitted. Your page redirects from /client to /client/login. Do you know how the errors are passed from the /client page to the /client/login page?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you have the login code itself at the top, if you need me to include the code of the error messages or whatever, let me know.

Comment: I found the actual problem. Your website does not even have a PHP session id cookie in Edge. This topic explains more about a possible cause:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048551/ie-edge-session-cookie-problems-using-cookie-lifetime
This might be somewhere in your website code, perhaps to create a longer session duration: session.cookie_lifetime

Comment: I found this: session.cookie_lifetime = 1440 in the php.ini - what should I make it then?